# Editing feature attributes (e.g. text field with typo) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, file-geodatabase

A feature class in a file geodatabase has a hand full of features where a text field is typo'd. How do I edit this to fix the typos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the feature class in ArcGIS Desktop, use the [Editor toolbar](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?topicname=editor_toolbar) to start editing the feature, and edit the text using either the Attribute tool (in the Editor toolbar) or in the attribute table. After you're done, save edits.

Comment: My problem was I had multiple feature class open in the mxd along the one I wished to edit. I closed all files and opened a blank mxd, added the feature, and did the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I sympathize with your "blank mxd" method. It often makes it simpler with too many layers.

Comment: Quirky software leads to very superstitious users...